# an expression of non-boolean type specified in a context sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I can't get this to work. arr! I'm trying to add additional AND if the @DiscountName is a certain value. Pretty much I'm trying to have additional AND statement IF the incoming parameter @DiscountName = "MyValue"

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_Discount_InsertDiscountBatch]
    @CustomerNumber Int,
    @DiscountName Varchar(50),
    ...
AS

        Select @currDate, [dbo].[TransactionActivity].Id
            From [dbo].[TransactionActivity]
            Where
                [dbo].[TransactionActivity].CustomerNumber = @CustomerNumber
                And 
                    Case When @DiscountName = 'Member' Then 
                        [dbo].[TransactionActivity].IsMember
                    Else ''
                    End
```

This is for MS SQL server.

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is unclear what you want.  Perhaps something like:

```
Where [dbo].[TransactionActivity].CustomerNumber = @CustomerNumber AND
      (@DiscountName <> 'Member' or [dbo].[TransactionActivity].IsMember = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I Found the solution here: http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2003/11/14/513.aspx

`WHERE @Filter<>1 OR (Date= @Date and Cust= @Cust and Emp= @Emp`)